# Google map not working api v1 on device

Tags: android

I am trying to display google map in my app using google map api v1. I have added required permissions and libraries in my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and set API_KEY in map layout.

Please suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: have you added the google play services library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use`[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

[Google Maps Android v1 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/)

Comment: @user2978175 How you have requested for the API key as its already closed by google for requesting the API key for V1.

Comment: had generated api key earlier.

Comment: Is there any other way to make it work without conversion from api1 to api2

Comment: No, Its not possible. You will have to switch to Google Map V2 as the Document of google map say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Google map API v1 is deprecated try to implement in Google map API v2

[Introduction to Google map API v2 Document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)

Answer (score 0):

Google map API v1 is deprecated please implement Google map API v2.But you havent include the meta tag

Add `<metadata>` tag in the manifest folder under `<application>` tag

for ex.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v1.API_KEY"
    android:value="your API KEY"/>
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by switching from API V1 to API V2.